# Type of line drawing in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I try to use graphviz to draw graph with minimum crossing number to make it understandable. Graphviz do it well with default settings, but sometimes it create many intersections of outgoing arrows.[image: intersections of outgoing arrows]
Can I change the style of drawing lines outgoing using DOT language? Problem lines is

```
33->105; 
33->73; 
33->45;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `dot` for your layout, you may try using [`concentrate=true`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:concentrate) which does merge edges in some cases:

Example:

[image: graphviz edge concentrate]

[image: the other way around]

Comment: "dotty" and "xdot" tools ignore this option. What tools is good for it?

Comment: is it also possible to force Graphviz to concentrate also all edges which go from rank1 to rank2 (d->f, d->e, d->g, d->c )? i can see in the last Graph that only the edges are concentrated from rank1 to rank3 (d->h, d->b)